# want to know about the function whose first derivative exist but second derivative does not exist

Tags: algebra-precalculus

when we study about taylor's theorem we deals with the functions whose first and all other derivative exist. 
 i want to know about an algebrac or trignometric function whose first derivative exist but second derivative doesnot exist. 
     this is my basic question.

Comment: Do you want an example of a function with a continuous derivative but discontinuous second derivative or do you want to know about approximation properties of such functions?

Comment: For an example involving trigonometric functions take $x\mapsto\sin(x|x|)$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Construct a function whose derivative is given by

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0 & \text{ if }x\leq 0\\ x &\text{ if }x>0\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 3):

Start with a continuous, non-differentiable function $g$ on the whole reals, say.

Define your function as
$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g(t) dt.
$$